# Troubles displaying 2d array read from txt file (C++)

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, file-io

I'm having troubles doing a loop for a really basic console game that uses ASCII characters. I want to store the txt file (the map) into a 2d array and then I want to output the 2d array on the console.

You can see 2 loops under here, one for inputting the txt file into a 2d array and the other for outputting the 2d array on the screen.

```
void Level::load_level() {
    Level gameLevel;
    ifstream inFile;
    gameLevel.map;

    inFile.open("level1.txt");
    if (inFile.fail()) {
        perror("level1.txt");
        system("PAUSE");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 74; j++) {
            inFile >> map[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 74; j++) {
            printf("%c", map[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    inFile.close();
}
```

So, here is what my txt file looks like:

[image]

And here is what my console displays:

[image]

It seems like the data in the 2d array isn't store correctly, what should I do in order to keep one loop reading data from the file into a 2d array and another loop displaying the 2d array correctly? I don't know if I made that clear.
Thanks and sorry for my lack of skill(I'm a beginner).

Comment: What's `map`? Show a [mcve]

Comment: is the txt file that I want to store in the 2d array(the map of the game).

Comment: I mean, how is this variable declared, and how is its type implemented? The problem is in the code you haven't shown; most likely, a buffer overrun in `map[i][j]`

Comment: Oh yeah sorry,  is a public variable in the class: char map[74][20]

Comment: Then you access it out of bounds, whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior. The second index must be between 0 and 19; you use as high as 73

Comment: lol I'm dumb, thank you sir, you are a lifesaver

Comment: What does `gameLevel.map;` do (probably not what you think it does)?